# "Retryable" requests and CancellationToken/CancellationTokenSource

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource

I'm adding new functionality to a Windows Forms application where after a user fills out a collection of address fields, I wait a few seconds before querying the geocode of that address through the US Census's geocoding API.  It is possible that the user will not enter the correct information the first time and they will need to fix the data and re-request.  When that happens, I want to cancel the request and submit a new one.  The request is being started from a System.Timers.Timer event callback which currently uses an existing CancellationTokenSource stored in a field on the form's view model and passes the CancellationTokenSource's Token to Task.Run and to the async lambda function that it's running like this:

```
private void OnServiceAddressChangedTimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    Task.Run(async () => {
        var geocode = await Geocoder.GetGeocodeAsync(
            ServiceAddress.Line1,
            ServiceAddress.Line2,
            ServiceAddress.City,
            ServiceAddress.State,
            ServiceAddress.Zip,
            _gpsLookupCancellationSource.Token
        );

        GPSCoordinates.Latitude = geocode?.Latitude;
        GPSCoordinates.Longitude = geocode?.Longitude;
    }, _gpsLookupCancellationSource.Token);
}
```

The problem I'm having is in the OnServiceAddressChanged function (currently called every time the text in the address fields change, that'll eventually be changed to either when the user leaves the field or triggered by a button, but anyway), when the data changes, I'm canceling the _gpsLookupCancellationSource so when I reuse it later in the OnServiceAddressChangedTimerElapsed function, it's already cancelled:

```
private void OnServiceAddressChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ServiceAddress.Line1) &&
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ServiceAddress.City) &&
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ServiceAddress.State) &&
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ServiceAddress.Zip)
    )
    {
        _serviceAddressChangedTimer.Stop();
        _gpsLookupCancellationSource.Cancel();
        _serviceAddressChangedTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Though I think I understand why it's not working right now (because the CTS was already cancelled after the first change to the field), I don't understand the right way to handle the _gpsLookupCancellationSource.  I think that when the OnServiceAddressChanged function runs, it should cancel the old source and then create a new one before restarting the timer but I can't Dispose it because it's my understanding the Tokens created from it likely hold a reference to that source to know that it's been deleted and checking if it was canceled will likely result in an ObjectDisposedException.  What's the right way to do this? Would it be okay to dispose the CTS while its Tokens may or may not be checking their IsCancellationRequested properties? Do I even need to explicitly dispose the CTS?  Is there a much simpler way to do all of this that I've totally overlooked?  Thanks to anyone who reads this for your time!

Comment: 'Fire and forget' `Task`s are ugly. `await` them. You should create a new `CancellationTokenSource` instance each time you run a `Task`. And don't forget to finally `Dispose` it each time.

Comment: @dymanoid Thanks for your comments, that post answered my question. I know that I should await tasks but I don't know how to do that when the task is being started from a synchronous function. Now that I know you can cancel the source and the tokens referencing it will still work, I think I know what to do.